# How do I compare whether my selected calendar endtime is earlier than selected calendar starttime on a 12 hour calendar time?

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-timepicker, android-date

I am trying to cross check if my selected calendar endtime is earlier than my selected calendar starttime on a 12 hour time period.
Currently I am using 2 different attributes to store selected calendar starttime and endtime as follows:

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePickerDialog view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
    String am_pm = "";

    Calendar datetime = Calendar.getInstance();
    datetime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    datetime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

    if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
        am_pm = "AM";
    else if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
        am_pm = "PM";

    String strHrsToShow = (datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0) ?"12":datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR)+"";
    String strMinsToShow = minute < 10 ? "0"+minute : ""+minute;

    if (isStartTimeClicked) {
        starttime.setText(String.format("%s:%s %s", strHrsToShow, strMinsToShow, am_pm));
    } else {
        endtime.setText(String.format("%s:%s %s", strHrsToShow, strMinsToShow, am_pm));
    }
    isStartTimeClicked = false;
}
```

I just want to compare both of these start and end times selected such that, end time cannot be earlier or equal to starttime. (it has to be after start time, say starttime is 2pm, endtime should be atleast 2:01pm or later and cant be 11am etc). 
even a boolean function showing that the selected end time is earlier or later than start time will suffice, but i am not sure how to go about this on a 12 hour time period scale based on my code as shown above.
Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

Function I use for timepicker:

```
   public void openMyTimePicker() {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                this,
                now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                false
        );
        tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
    }
```

Comment: You can convert your time to 24hr format and then can compare it. (I am guessing that for given case 2.01pm, 11pm will be allowed)

Comment: It doesn’t answer your question, but don’t hand format your time strings. Nice work, but too cumbersome, also for those reading your code after you. Use a formatter. The modern version would be something like `LocalTime.of(hourOfDay, minute, second).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(Locale.US))`.

Comment: With so much date and time work in your app consider not using the long outmoded and poorly designed `Calendar` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your end-time timepicker `onTimeSet()` check time set in start-time timepicker

```
//You will need to declare enddatetime and startdatetime at class level
if (enddatetime.getTimeInMillis() >= startdatetime.getTimeInMillis()) {
    int hour = hourOfDay % 12;
    btnPickStartTime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d %s", hour == 0 ? 12 : hour,
                            minute, hourOfDay < 12 ? "am" : "pm"));
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // before time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Date.after` or `Date.before` functionality

```
//Compare Date
if (endDate.before(startDate)) {
    //End date is before start date
} else {
    //End date is after start date
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it doesnt recognize am/pm format.for example  It somehow thinks 2am  is after 1pm based on the value instead of the timeframe

Comment: What value are you passing in as endDate and startDate? They need to be Calendar.time. If you could post an example project to GitHub I can edit it for you to show you what I mean. 

Date.after doesn't care about am/pm because it uses Date.getMillisOf so you are either not passing in the correct values to the function or are not calling Date.after

Comment: I added the function I use for timepicker in calendar to my question. I also have starttime and endtime I pass listed out in on time set function. They are textviews I define in my xml. I am not doing anything out of the functions listed in my question. they are both calendar times , only not sure if   String strHrsToShow = (datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0) ?"12":datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR)+"";
    String strMinsToShow = minute < 10 ? "0"+minute : ""+minute;
 affects anything with regards to manipulating after and before params as you mentioned